# How to change the state in react with a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, state

I have a form that is supposed to update the initial state, I've followed many tutorials and my code looks the same as them but for some reason it doesn't update the state.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Create extends Component{
   constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = {
         title: "",
         body: "",
         error: ""
      } 
   }

   onTitleChange(e) {
      const title = e.target.value;
      this.setState({title})
   }

   onBodyChange(e) {
      const body = e.target.value;
      this.setState({body})
   }

   onSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if(!this.state.title || !this.state.body){
         this.setState(() => ({ error: "Please fill in all gaps"}))
      } else {
         this.setState(() => ({ error: "" }))
         // Send info to the main page
         alert(this.state.title);
      }
   }

   render(){
      return(
         <div>
         {this.state.error && <p>{this.state.error}</p>}
         <form onSubmit = {this.onSubmit}>
         <label>Put a title for your note</label>
         <input 
            placeholder="Title"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.title}
            autoFocus
            onChange= {this.onTitleChange}
         />
         <label>Write your note</label>
         <textarea 
            placeholder="Note"
            value={this.state.body}
            autoFocus
            onChange = {this.onBodyChange}
         />
         <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
         </form>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default Create;
```

When I check the current state in the React developer tools it shows that the state remains the same and I don't know why because there are not errors in the log.
I'm working with webpack, babel and react.

////////////////////
EDITED
////////////////////

I edited my code following the suggestions you guys gave me but still it doesn't work. An alert is supposed to appear when submitted the form but that doesn't get fired either, so I believe that non of the functions are getting fired.

This is my edited code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Create extends Component{
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.onTitleChange = this.onTitleChange.bind(this);
      this.onBodyChange = this.onBodyChange.bind(this);
      this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

      this.state = {
         title: "",
         body: "",
         error: ""
      } 
   }

   onTitleChange(e) {
      const title = e.target.value;
      this.setState((prevState) => {
         return {
           ...prevState,
           title
         };
       });
   }

   onBodyChange(e) {
      const body = e.target.value;
      this.setState((prevState) => {
         return {
           ...prevState,
           body
         };
       });
   }

   onSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if(!this.state.title || !this.state.body){
         this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
              ...prevState,
              error: "Please fill in all gaps"
            };
          });
      } else {
         this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
              ...prevState,
              error: ""
            };
          });
         // Send info to the main page
         alert(this.state.title);
      }
   }

   render(){
      return(
         <div>
         {this.state.error && <p>{this.state.error}</p>}
         <form onSubmit = {this.onSubmit}>
         <label>Put a title for your note</label>
         <input 
            placeholder="Title"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.title}
            autoFocus
            onChange= {this.onTitleChange}
         />
         <label>Write your note</label>
         <textarea 
            placeholder="Note"
            value={this.state.body}
            autoFocus
            onChange = {this.onBodyChange}
         />
         <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
         </form>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default Create;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try binding the event handlers in the constructor, because it seems like `this` within those event handling functions could be undefined. The [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) outlines why the binding is necessary, and here's another useful page on [handling forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) in React.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  ...
  this.onTitleChange = this.onTitleChange.bind(this);
  this.onBodyChange = this.onBodyChange.bind(this);
  this.onSubmitChange = this.onSubmitChange.bind(this);
}
```

An alternative to binding in the constructor would also be to use arrow functions for your event handlers which implicitly bind `this`.

```js
class Create extends Component {
    ...

    onTitleChange = () => { ... }
    onBodyChange = () => { ... }
    onSubmitChange = () => { ... }
}
```

EDIT: Can't comment on your post since my reputation is too low, but it seems like there's a typo in the changes you just made.

`this.onSubmitC = this.onSubmit.bind(this)` should be changed to

`this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)`

Comment: You're right! I fixed that too but it doen's work

Comment: I also noticed that in your `setState` calls you were including the `prevState` when its not necessary. You only need to pass an object with the new state you require for a particular field, and react will merge the new state and previous state objects under the hood for you. I was able to get it to work in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r3qcvpk8/1/) check it out

Answer (score 0):

React's `setState()` accepts an object, not a function. So change your `onSubmit()` to this:

```
if(!this.state.title || !this.state.body){
    this.setState({ error: "Please fill in all gaps"})
} else {
    this.setState({ error: "" })
    // Send info to the main page
    alert(this.state.title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It better to use the previous state and only update the required (input value) values.

in your case you are replacing the existing state (whole object) just with the title and the same goes for body `onBodyChange`

```
 onTitleChange () {
    const title = e.target.value;
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        title
      };
    });
  };
<
```

Comment: let’s check it together. if u want. when do u have time?

Comment: This isn't true by the the way, react will perform a shallow merge of the existing state and updated state for you. [Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged)

Comment: @FoundingBox Thank you. Good to know :)